# AWS CLI remove only metadata

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

To remove all files in an s3 bucket I can run:

```
aws s3 rm --recursive s3://bucket
```

How do I remove only the metadata from the bucket?

Comment: How do you define "metadata" on the bucket? Where is it visible? How was it added initially?

Comment: When I make an Athena query, 2 files are written to my bucket, a csv and a .metadata file

Comment: So your question is how to delete all objects with Keys that end with `.csv.metadata`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to delete all objects with keys that end with `.csv.metadata`, you can use:

```
aws s3 rm --recursive s3://my-bucket/ --exclude "*" --include "*.csv.metadata"
```

See: [Use of Exclude and Include Filters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/index.html#use-of-exclude-and-include-filters)

Comment: This works! Thank you for pointing me to the documentation for it, I missed that section